# callback of omniauth facebook displays an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

app/models/user.rb:9:in `apply_omniauth'
 app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:18:in`create'

I have been trying this from the tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2.

what should i do?

Update:

i found the mistake but still after signing in, the callback comes to the signup page. Also i found nothing saved in model.

Comment: Can you post your app/models/user.rb and app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb scripts?, it is hard to help without them

Comment: Even after your update, posting that code would really help.